# Connect two nodes with multiple edges in vis.js

Tags: reactjs, vis.js

I recently started using visj with react and I wanted to know if there's an option to display multiple edges between two nodes?
Right now I have the problem that I can connect two nodes by multiple edges, but they collapse to one line so that it is not visible that there are actually various edges.

Comment: Someone just upvoted this and I found a fix for that so here it goes: Each link in visjs has a "smooth" object, that contains an "active" and "roundness" property. Setting the active to true and giving each link a different roundness will make the links appear on the screen.